# How about initializition a bean's property with enum?

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have a enumeration:

```
package com.stardust.emul;

public enum BonusTypes{
    BIRTHDAY,
    REGISTRATION,
    ACTIVE
}
```

and classes to be a spring's bean (All form the package `com.stardust.utils`):

```
public interface BonusProcessor{

    public void processBonus();

}

public class BirthdayBonusProcessor implements BonusProcessor{

    //implementation

}

//and so forth

public class VisualService{
    Map<BonusTypes, BonusProcessor> processors;
    //Other staff
}
```

***Question***: How can I specify the value of a enumeration type in a spring cofiguration file?

In my particular case I'd like to write something like that:

```
<bean id="birthdayProcessor class="com.stardust.utils.BirthdayBonusProcessor />

<bean id="visualService" class="com.stardust.utils.VisualService">
    <property name="processors">
        <map>
            <entry key ="__BonusTypes.BIRTHDAY__should_be_here" value-ref="birthdayProcessor"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</beans>
```

Comment: Why not use Java code rather than XML? It would be so much easier, safe, and refactorable. That said, AFAIK, BIRTHDAY should work fine. Searching for "enum" in the docymentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) shows several examples.

Comment: @JBNizet The reason why I prefer to use xml is that the things will be in the same, therfore, I think, it would be more simply to understand. Why don't?

Comment: *the things will be in the same*: what does that mean?

Comment: @JBNizet I meant in the same place.

Comment: And why wouldn't they be in the same place when using Java code? Read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java

Comment: @JBNizet Just because in our projects we use xml-based configuration. Do you think it's a good idea to mix these two approaches?

Comment: No. I would go full Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring is smart enough to convert a `String` to an `enum` type if that value is the name of the `enum` constant. Just specify the key type of your map.

```
<bean id="visualService" class="com.stardust.utils.VisualService">
    <property name="processors">
        <map key-type="com.fully.qualified.BonusTypes">
            <entry key="BIRTHDAY" value-ref="birthdayProcessor" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```